# Liquibase "Load Data" throws Error 1218 with this file on DB2

Tags: csv, db2, liquibase, db2-luw

I want to load some initial Data into my DB2 Database with the Liquibase "Load-Data"-Tag. It works with the 70 other files just fine, but it throws this Error with one specific file.

```
SQLCODE=-1218, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=4096
```

### Already attempted fixes

I already tried all the possible fixes in the db2 documentation, but the Problem persisited:

```
1. increase the bufferpool size

2. decrease the maximum number of database agents and/or connections

3. decrease the maximum degree of parallelism

4. decrease the prefetch size for table spaces that are in this
   bufferpool

5. move some table spaces into other bufferpools.
```

The original file-size was over 4000 lines but even when decreasing the size it still throws the error when one of the following lines is in the csv (examples, there are more of these lines):

```
"0141.651       ";"004";"default                 ";"-     Valor neto en %                                                                               "
"0144.654       ";"002";"default                 ";"-     Net Value as %                                                                                "
"0311.000-TC    ";"002";"default                 ";"Raw Materials, Supplies                                  "
```

### Code

Following there is my initialisation of the bufferpool, the tablespace, the table and the liquibase script:

```
CREATE BUFFERPOOL BPDAT SIZE 5000 PAGESIZE 4 K;

CREATE TABLESPACE TSBLCORE MANAGED BY DATABASE USING (FILE 'tsblcore.001' 200000) BUFFERPOOL BPDAT;
```

```
    create table BLPDET
(
    SYMBOLICPOSITIONNO CHAR(15)  not null,
    LANGUAGEKEY        CHAR(3)   not null,
    REPORTGROUPKEY     CHAR(24)  not null,
    DESCRIPTION        CHAR(100) not null
) in TSBLCORE;
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd"
>
<changeSet author="Jonas" id="4.31">
    <sql>COMMIT;</sql>
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="build/Server/resources/changelog/Data/BL_POSDESCRIPTION.csv"
              commentLineStartsWith=""
              quotchar="&quot;"
              relativeToChangelogFile="false"
              schemaName="DB5"
              separator=";"
              tableName="BLPDET"
              usePreparedStatements="false">
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

### Error

This is the Error displayed in the logs:

```
2022-08-18-10.58.09.909950+000 I424271E825           LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 12733                TID : 140309988108032 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : DB2LOCAL
APPHDL  : 0-503                APPID: 172.17.0.1.55526.220818105144
UOWID   : 366                  ACTID: 142            
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: d4fac55a3d2e
EDUID   : 48                   EDUNAME: db2agent (DB2LOCAL) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbIsExtentAllocated, probe:4792
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8502002C=-2063466452=SQLB_BPFULL
          "no available buffer pool pages"
DATA #1 : Pointer, 8 bytes
0x00007f9c366bc3c8
DATA #2 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
4
DATA #3 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
0
DATA #4 : Pointer, 8 bytes
0x00007f9c76ffc0d0
DATA #5 : Pointer, 8 bytes
0x00007f9c64d77440
```

I tried to raise my number of pages up to like 100,000, but the error persisted.

db2diag.log:

```
ADM6019E All pages in buffer pool "IBMSYSTEMBP4K" (ID "4096") are in use. Refer to the documentation for SQLCODE -1218

ADM6073W The table space "TSBLCORE" (ID "8") is configured to use buffer pool ID "3", but this buffer pool is not active at this time. In the interim the table space will use buffer pool ID "4096". The inactive buffer pool should become available at next database startup provided that the required memory is available.
```

### Environment

Database Product
DB2/LINUXX8664

Database Version
SQL11055

Driver Version
4.8

Liquibase Version
4.14.0

Is there any possibility that something in the example datasets causes this behaviour?

PS: This is my first Stackoverflow Question, so please excuse me if i forgot to include something.

Comment: The SQLERRMC=4096 suggests Db2 may have a problem with  the pagesize. Does your CSV file import or load using the native Db2 command-line tools (i.e. this might not be a liquibase matter)? So it is worth to double check this.

Comment: Please check your Db2-LUW server diagnostics file (e.g. db2diag.log) for more information about the error. If you have a DBA, ask for help with that, otherwise use SQL to query `SYSIBMADM.PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS` (look it up in the Db2 knowledge center).   Also check if this CSV file can be imported using the native db2 clp import command.

Comment: @mao Thanks a lot! I specified the Versions for the relevant Plugins in the questions. Because I run the Database in Docker and im not to familliar with docker I dont know how to import a local csv from there so I couldnt do the db2 import statement, but a custom Java-Script, which uses prepared statements works perfectly fine.

Comment: It's unclear if the custom java uses the exact same csv file that gives the problem, so cannot tell the relevance.  Please check db2diag.log and update your question with the messages that appear only when liquibase loadData runs and fails.  To access the db2diag, either shell into the container and become the instance owner (e.g. db2inst1) and look in /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/db2diag.log (or use `find` to locate that file db2diag.log ), or use SQL to query as per previous comment.

Comment: @mao Okay, i ran the comand, the newest entry said: 
ADM6019E  All pages in buffer pool "IBMSYSTEMBP4K" (ID "4096") are in use.  
Refer to the documentation for SQLCODE -1218.
And an older one, states: 
ADM6073W  The table space "TSBLCORE" (ID "8") is configured to use buffer pool 
ID "3", but this buffer pool is not active at this time. In the interim the 
table space will use buffer pool ID "4096".  The inactive buffer pool should 
become available at next database startup provided that the required memory is 
available.

Comment: I find this to be quiet interesting, because it basically means that the bufferpool isnt active yet, but even when restarting the create table space statements, the same msg appears.

Comment: What happens if you __either__ allow that bufferpool to have automatic sizing (`alter bufferpool BPDAT size automatic`) . or manually alter its size (` alter bufferpool BPDAT SIZE 50000`) or just put these settings(sizes) in your script at creation time ?

Comment: That unfortianatly doesnt change anything, but when I let the sql script run manually before i run liquibase:update it works and for now that works for me. Many thanks to you, the information you gave where quite helpful even outside the original topic!